# Getting error when creating docker image of jar file

Tags: java, docker, jar

I tried several times by removing docker image and pulling the docker image, but getting the same error. Not getting the solution and I'm new to docker, help me to solve this error.

**/bin/sh: [java,-jar,/tmp/hello-world-rest-api.jar]: not found**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdpgb.jpg)

Comment: How did you created container?

Comment: Please check with image **enter image description here**

Comment: What if you try to escape the quote (`"`) marks with a backslash (`\ `)?

Comment: Have you tried creating a DOCKERFILE and then building the image by docker build

Comment: Present i'm running project using dockerfile. But i'm getting problem when I'm doing manual

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the actual command you're running, and your Dockerfile and any other relevant source code?  These should be as text directly in the question, not as an image and not behind a link.